# Schedule a batch file with parameters containing spaces

Tags: windows-server-2003, batch-file, scheduled-task

I need to schedule a task in Windows Server 2003 that executes this script that deletes files older that n days in the specified folder. The script needs 3 parameters:

```
%1 path to folder where files need to be deleted
%2 file names (es. *.log)
%3 number of days 

@echo off
forfiles -p %1 -s -m %2 -d -%3 -c "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

The script works fine if the first parameter has no spaces inside. This is an example of parameters that work:

```
"C:\Program Files\SCRIPT\DeleteFilesOlderThanXDays.cmd" N:\FOLDER\FOLDER *.zip 60
```

This is an example that does not work:

```
"C:\Program Files\SCRIPT\DeleteFilesOlderThanXDays.cmd" N:\Program Files\LOG *.zip 60
```

This does not work too:

```
"C:\Program Files\SCRIPT\DeleteFilesOlderThanXDays.cmd" "N:\Program Files\LOG" *.zip 60
```

I think it would be a quotes problem but I can't figure out the solution. I'd like not to insert values directly into the script if possible

Thank you all for help

Comment: do you get any error messages/etc. that indicate what the problem is? That should help to debug. The 3rd command line you posted (where the path is double-quoted) should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. After further investigations it comes out that the batch file should be modified adding quotes around @path to allow spaces:

@echo off 
forfiles -p %1 -s -m %2 -d -%3 -c "cmd /c del /q "@path""

The path parameter has to be quoted too as follows because of spaces:

"C:\Program Files\SCRIPT\DeleteFilesOlderThanXDays.cmd" "N:\Program Files\LOG" *.zip 60

Now, it does not work too because having "C:\Program Files\SCRIPT\DeleteFilesOlderThanXDays.cmd" followed by a quoted parameter fails with an error like "C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command..." so no luck again.

Workaround that works:

"C:\Program Files\SCRIPT\DeleteFilesOlderThanXDays.cmd" . *.zip 60

Start in: "N:\Program Files\LOG"

Answer (score 1):

Not a full solution, but a workaround that might get your task working until you find a better resolution: you could try calling a batch file that does not take parameters and does nothing but call `"C:\Program Files\SCRIPT\DeleteFilesOlderThanXDays.cmd" "N:\Program Files\LOG" *.zip 60`

Answer (score 0):

In your batch file add quotes around the parameters that can include spaces.
So, at least around %1.

```
@echo off forfiles -p "%1" -s -m %2 -d -%3 -c "cmd /c del /q "@path""
```